# Using socket.io in Cloud9 always get the xhr-polling transportation method

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, websocket, socket.io

I'm developing an app that uses socket.io, but it always fallback to xhr polling transportation method, and I can't understand why.

I'm using Chrome, but I already tested with other browsers, and the xhr polling transportation method still be used.

I'm using Cloud9 IDE in c9.io.

Have you ever saw this behaviour?

Comment: Do you use any kind of proxy?

Comment: I guess not. I moved the application to my localhost where I have nodeJs installed, and everything is working fine.

So maybe it's something related to Cloud9. I would like to know if someone was able to use websocket method transportation with Socket.io and Cloud9.

Comment: And how does localhost success prove that you don't use proxies to connect to the outer world? )

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Cloud9 - I think it is due to their server-side proxying system

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 IDE only supports xhr polling transportation method like heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku